# How can I get eslint to detect common React errors in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, eslintrc

My React Native project's eslinter doesn't seem to be picking up specific React errors in VSCode. **For instance, if I omit a required dependency from useEffect the linter doesn't
catch it.**

Note: using create-react-app, the linter works as expected though.

Is it possible to do with React Native? This is what I have:

```json
// package.json

"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

```js
// eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  extends: "airbnb",
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  env: {
    jest: true,
  },
  rules: {
    "comma-dangle": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "no-unsafe-optional-chaining": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "object-curly-newline": "off",
    "operator-linebreak": 0,
    quotes: [2, "double"],
    "spaced-comment": 0,
  },
  globals: {
    fetch: false,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the official react-native eslint configuration directly from facebook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/eslint-config). This package includes the [react-hooks eslint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks). For example, this plugin enables an error if a dependency is missing from a dependency array of a `useEffect`.

You can use it in your `.eslintrc.js` as follows.

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
     "airbnb",
     "@react-native-community"
  ]
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  env: {
    jest: true,
  },
  rules: {
    "comma-dangle": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    "no-unsafe-optional-chaining": "off",
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "object-curly-newline": "off",
    "operator-linebreak": 0,
    quotes: [2, "double"],
    "spaced-comment": 0,
  },
  globals: {
    fetch: false,
  },
};
```

Since implementing a react-native application means that we write a lot of Javascript code, it is recommended to add the usual recommended `eslint` rules as well via

```js
extends: [
     "airbnb",
     "@react-native-community",
     "eslint: recommended",
  ]
```

If you want warnings if a style in a `StyleSheet` is unused, then you can use the [eslint-plugin-react-native](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native). The setup is straight forward and very well documented.